# Get javascript code and modify it to execute chainable

Tags: javascript

I want to change my code to execute chaining. this is my code:

```
let stepCount = {
    step: 0,
    up() {
        this.step++;
    },
    down() {
        this.step--;
    },
    showStep: function () {
       return this.step;
    }
};
```

How should I change it?  I want to  execute this code to get answer

```
stepCount.up().up().down().up();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to return the current object from each function like this

```js
let stepCount = {
  step: 0,
  up() {
    this.step++;
    return this;
  },
  down() {
    this.step--;
    return this
  },
  showStep() {
    console.log(this.step)
    return this;
  }
};

stepCount.up().up().down().showStep().down().showStep();
```

Comment: I got error (down is not a function!!!!)
try this code:
```
stepCount.up().up().down().showStep().down().showStep();
```

Comment: updated the answer,please check it

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```js
class Step {
    constructor(count) {
        this.step = count;
    }

    up() {
        this.step++;
        return this;
    }

    down() {
        this.step--;
        return this;
    }
}

console.log(new Step(5).up().up().step); // 7
```

Comment: I prefer to code without class here